# Using themes in style sheets

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-stylesheet, darkmode

I am using react navigation's theme functionality to switch between dark and light mode and getting the colors for the mode with `const { colors } = useTheme();` However I am trying to set colors in a stylesheet. How should I go about doing this. I have been doing `{[styles.subtitle, colors.text]}` to set styles on components. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Such as setting the color inside the styles.subtitle object?

Answer (score 0):

Make your stylesheet in the body of your component. Define `const { colors } = useTheme();` and then directly beneath that (instead of at the bottom of the file), create your stylesheet